# Thread doesn't work with void as ThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have got two voids and want both to be processed with an own thread.

My main thread executes the first void (it is a loop) and should then start a new Thread which works with void two (also a loop)

I tried it like this:

```
Thread graphicsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(graphicsDoAction()));
```

...
Here is the graphicsDoWork void:

```
public void graphicsDoAction()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        while (true)
        {
            //GraphicsLoop
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case gameStateEnum.visualising:
                     g.DrawString("Loading...", menuFont, new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke), new PointF(100, this.Height / 2));
                     g = this.CreateGraphics();
                     g.DrawImage(Game2.Properties.Resources.bg, 0, 0, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
                     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    break;

                case gameStateEnum.mainMenu:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Somewhere in the code, my graphicsThread will be executed by using graphicsThread.Start();

I always get an error saying that my fieldinitialiser can't refer to a static function. graphicsDoAction() has got no static modifier, so why does it keep saying that?

Comment: 2 general rules you should know: 1) Avoid CreateGraphics(), 2) don't use Thread.Sleep().

Comment: And of course you can't do any GUI graphics in a Thread.